# Convert a CGImage to MTLTexture without premultiplication

Tags: swift, png, metal, metalkit, premultiplied-alpha

I have a UIImage which I've previously created from a png file:

```
let strokeUIImage = UIImage(data: pngData)
```

I want to convert strokeImage (which has opacity) to an `MTLTexture` for display in an `MTKView`, but doing the conversion seems to perform an unwanted premultiplication, which darkens all the semitransparent edges.

My blending settings are as follows:

```
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

I've tried two methods of conversion:

```
let stampTexture = try! MTKTextureLoader(device: self.device!).newTexture(cgImage: strokeUIImage.cgImage!, options: nil)
```

and the more elaborate dataProvider-driven method:

```
let image = strokeUIImage.cgImage!
    let imageWidth = image.width
    let imageHeight = image.height
    let bytesPerPixel:Int! = 4
    let rowBytes = imageWidth * bytesPerPixel        

    let texDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba8Unorm_srgb,
                                                              width: imageWidth,
                                                              height: imageHeight,
                                                              mipmapped: false)

    guard let stampTexture = device!.makeTexture(descriptor: texDescriptor) else { return }

    let srcData: CFData! = image.dataProvider?.data
    let pixelData = CFDataGetBytePtr(srcData)

    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)
    stampTexture.replace(region: region, mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: pixelData!, bytesPerRow: Int(rowBytes))
```

both of which yield the same unwanted premultiplied result.

The latter I tried, as there were some posts suggesting that the old swift3 method `CGDataProviderCopyData()` extracts raw pixel data from the image which is not premultiplied.  Sadly, the equivalent:

```
let srcData: CFData! = image.dataProvider?.data
```

does not seem to do the trick. Am I missing something?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to use an Accelerate function such as `vImageUnpremultiplyData_ARGB8888` to go from associated data to unassociated data, but I'd encourage you to use a different blending mode if you're seeing issues related to edge darkening. Correct compositing is much easier if you use premultiplied colors throughout your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, Warren. I've updated the question to include the blending mode info. All I'm trying to do is to composite the png data to an MTKView drawable. Period. But doing so seems to perform this pre-multiplication even on an empty view, and I'm not sure where this is happening. It seems like a legacy issue, as lots of posts basically ask the same question, but I've not seen a definitive answer.  How would I use the accelerate function you suggest? Any further thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All images loaded from CoreGraphics will pre-multiply the non-opaque pixels. I have looked before at loading directly with libpng but the problem is non-trivial.

Comment: I've posted an answer below which gets me 95% of the way there...Thanks to Warrenm for pointing me in the direction of Accelerate functions

Answer (score 2):

After much experimenting, I've come to a solution which addresses the pre-multiplication issue inherent in CoreGraphics images.  Thanks to Warren's tip regarding using an Accelerate function (`vImageUnpremultiplyData_ARGB8888` in particular), I thought, why not build a CGImage using `vImage_CGImageFormat` which will allow me to play with the bitmapInfo setting that specifies how to interpret alpha...The result is not perfect, as demonstrated by the image attachment below:

[image: UIImage to MTLTexture]

Somehow, in the translation the alpha values are getting punched up slightly, (possibly the rgb as well, but not significantly).  By the way, I should point out that the png pixel format is sRGB, and the MTKView I'm using is set to `MTLPixelFormat.rgba16Float` (app requirement)

Below is the full metalDrawStrokeUIImage routine I implemented. Of particular note is the line:

```
bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue)
```

which essentially unassociates the alpha (I think) without calling `vImageUnpremultiplyData_ARGB8888`.  Looking at the resulting image certainly looks like an un-premultiplied image...

Lastly, to get back a premultiplied texture on the MTKView side, I let the fragment shader handle the pre-multiplication:

```
fragment float4 premult_fragment(VertexOut interpolated [[stage_in]],
                                 texture2d<float> texture [[texture(0)]],
                                 sampler sampler2D [[sampler(0)]]) {
  float4 sampled = texture.sample(sampler2D, interpolated.texCoord);

  // this fragment shader premultiplies incoming rgb with texture's alpha

  return float4(sampled.r * sampled.a,
                sampled.g * sampled.a,
                sampled.b * sampled.a,
                sampled.a );


} // end of premult_fragment
```

The result is pretty close to the input source, but the image is maybe 5% more opaque than the incoming png.  Again, png pixel format is sRGB, and the MTKView I'm using to display is set to `MTLPixelFormat.rgba16Float` .  So, I'm sure something is getting mushed somewhere.  If anyone has any pointers, I'd sure appreciate it.

Below is the rest of the relevant code:

```
func metalDrawStrokeUIImage (strokeUIImage: UIImage, strokeBbox: CGRect) {

self.metalSetupRenderPipeline(compStyle: compMode.strokeCopy) // needed so stampTexture is not modified by fragmentFunction

let bytesPerPixel = 4
let bitsPerComponent = 8

let width = Int(strokeUIImage.size.width)
let height = Int(strokeUIImage.size.height)

let rowBytes = width * bytesPerPixel
//
let texDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba8Unorm_srgb,
                                                             width: width,
                                                             height: height,
                                                             mipmapped: false)
guard let stampTexture = device!.makeTexture(descriptor: texDescriptor) else { return }

//let cgImage: CGImage = strokeUIImage.cgImage!
//let sourceColorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace else {
guard
  let cgImage = strokeUIImage.cgImage,
  let sourceColorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace else {
    print("Unable to initialize cgImage or colorSpace.")
    return
}

var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(
  bitsPerComponent: UInt32(cgImage.bitsPerComponent),
  bitsPerPixel: UInt32(cgImage.bitsPerPixel),
  colorSpace: Unmanaged.passRetained(sourceColorSpace),
  bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue),
  version: 0, decode: nil,
  renderingIntent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
var sourceBuffer = vImage_Buffer()

defer {
  free(sourceBuffer.data)
}

var error = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&sourceBuffer, &format, nil, cgImage, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags))

guard error == kvImageNoError else {
  print ("[MetalBrushStrokeView]: can't vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage")
  return

}

//vImagePremultiplyData_RGBA8888(&sourceBuffer, &sourceBuffer, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags))


// create a CGImage from vImage_Buffer
var destCGImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&sourceBuffer, &format, nil, nil, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags), &error)?.takeRetainedValue()


guard error == kvImageNoError else {
  print ("[MetalBrushStrokeView]: can't vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer")
  return
}

let dstData: CFData = (destCGImage!.dataProvider!.data)!
let pixelData = CFDataGetBytePtr(dstData)

destCGImage = nil

let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, Int(width), Int(height))
stampTexture.replace(region: region, mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: pixelData!, bytesPerRow: Int(rowBytes))
let stampColor = UIColor.white
let stampCorners = self.stampSetVerticesFromBbox(bbox: strokeBbox)
self.stampAppendToVertexBuffer(stampLayer: stampLayerMode.stampLayerFG, stampCorners: stampCorners, stampColor: stampColor)
self.metalRenderStampSingle(stampTexture: stampTexture)
self.initializeStampArray() // clears out the stamp array so we always draw 1 stamp at a time


} // end of func metalDrawStrokeUIImage (strokeUIImage: UIImage, strokeBbox: CGRect)
```